# Unreal Expose Terrain Layers via a blueprint

Tags: unreal-4, materials, blueprints, path

I have the below play area and I have 4 terrain materials defined in a material and attached to the terrain.
What I want to achieve is a way to use a blueprint to expose the pathway layer through the entire maze while avoiding collisions.

Terrain
[image: Sample level terrain]

Terrain Material
[image]

This is what I wanted to achieve programattically via a blueprint with the path. By collision I mean it cant go through trees, rocks, bushes or walls with colliders on them.

[image]

Comment: Im not sure I follow. I thought the idea of having layers on the terrain material was to expose those on the terrain where appropriate. Example or link to reference of what you are suggesting?

Comment: Edited my question for clarity